# Error backup online database,archivelog,control file using two channel

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, rman

I need to Backup your online database, archivelog and control file using two channel but I have some problem with it.

**My code:**

```
run{
     allocate channel c1 device type desk controlfile 1;
     allocate channel c2 device type desk controlfile 1;
     backup
     incremental level=0
     format 'C:\mamoun_batoul_aghiad_%d_%s_%p.bak'
     format 'd:\mamoun_batoul_aghiad_%d_%s_%p.bak'
     archivelog from sequence=4;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Starting backup at 06-NOV-19
using channel ORA_DISK_1
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of backup command at 11/06/2019 05:14:17
RMAN-06018: duplicate operand specified in backup specification: DFORMAT

 '  RMAN> }'

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00558: error encountered while parsing input commands
RMAN-01009: syntax error: found "}": expecting one of: "advise, allocate, alter, backup, @, catalog, change, configure, connect, convert, copy, create, crosscheck, delete, drop, duplicate, exit, flashback, grant, host, import, list, mount, open, print, quit, recover, register, release, repair, replace, report, reset, restore, resync, revoke, run, send, set, show, shutdown, spool, sql, startup, switch, transport, unregister, upgrade, validate, {, "
RMAN-01007: at line 1 column 1 file: standard input
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your format commands in your allocation section, eg

```
RUN
{
  ALLOCATE CHANNEL disk1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/disk1/backups/%U'; 
  ALLOCATE CHANNEL disk2 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT '/disk2/backups/%U'; 
  ...
}
```